# Form request not working for controllers within subfolder of Controller folder

Tags: laravel-5

My folder structure for controllers is: 
[image: controller folder structure]

and I use following route code to access those controllers.

here I have allocated sub-folders inside Controller folder and updated namespaces as per needed on files and routes accordingly, this works perfectly, however when I use request file for validating form. It gives error:

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\site\usersController::store()
must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given
```

but when I move all controllers file to Controller folder and don't use sub-folder,form request validation works.My usersController and UserRegReq request files are:

**usersController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\zcms;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Services\FieldService;
use App\Services\UserService;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\UserRegReq;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class usersController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(FieldService $field, UserService $user)
    {

        $this->field = $field;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function throwLogin()
    {

        return view('zcms.pages.login');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $field = $this->field->fieldList();

        return view('zcms.users.addnew', compact('field'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(UserRegReq $request)
    {
        return "hello";
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request $request
     * @param  int $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**UserRegReq.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class UserRegReq extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'field_id' => 'required',
            'name'     => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
    }


    // public function messages(){
    //     return [
    //         'field_id.required'=>'The related Field of your Job is required',
    //     ];
    // }
}
```

What should I do beside updating namespace in routes and controller file to make everything work?

Comment: Does you store method have a parameter request ?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ  I have uploaded my controller and request class

Comment: I have corrected your layout/question and vote up to give it more attention, so other can give look at your code for contribution.

Comment: Would you share the view file, because currently you are posting data to the wrong action?